# pandoc output in markdown: how to add the metadata

Tags: pandoc

A process takes a file in markdown format, parses it with pandoc to AST, changes some words in the text, and writes the resulting pandoc structure back to a markdown file.

This works except that the metadata which is included in the original file and is parsed by the pandoc input (extension: `Ext_yaml_metadata_block` is set) but is not included in the markdown output (extension there is only `writerSetextHeaders`).

What additional extension are needed? Or, do I need a different output template, including
something like `$Meta$` (with the `---` before and after)? Pointers to a solution greatly appreciated.

Should a template like this work?

```
$if(meta)$
---
$Meta$
---

$endif$

$if(titleblock)$ $titleblock$

$endif$ $for(header-includes)$ $header-includes$

$endfor$ $for(include-before)$ $include-before$

$endfor$ $if(toc)$ $table-of-contents$

$endif$ $body$ $for(include-after)$

$include-after$ $endfor$
```

Answer (score 3):

It sound like you are missing the `-s`/`--standalone` flag (`optStandalone` in Haskell). Without this option pandoc just outputs Markdown snippets, not a full document.

Comment: I can only find a `ReaderOption` `readerStandalone`, but nothing for the writer?  where should it  be? I tried with using the `WriterOption` `writerTemplate :: Maybe String` and put the template I have suggested, but this return only the name of the template in the output.

Comment: The issue with the template I fixed (the function needs a string as input, not the filename), but the result remains the same.

Comment: @user855443 checkout [Text.Pandoc.App.convertWithOpts](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/52a73abfe407317c32eb8d0f839e01c584b9e9d4/src/Text/Pandoc/App.hs#L68) for an easy solution, or try setting `writerTemplate` to a template.

Comment: I tried a template, but do not get the metadata inserted. I looked at `convertWithOpts` but could not see how it solves the issue. I need to add a function between the reading and the writing. I created a minimal working example and post this as a separate question.